# Calling WebService on JSF

Tags: web-services, jsf

i want to call webservice on JSF index page. how can i authentication?
thats my main code without jsf.

[project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Jck.png)

my main

```
    GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();

    GeoIPServiceSoap soap = service.getGeoIPServiceSoap();

    GeoIP geoIP = soap.getGeoIP("195.142.175.195");

    System.out.println(geoIP.getCountryName());

    System.out.println(geoIP.getCountryCode());

    System.out.println(geoIP.getIP());

    System.out.println(geoIP.getReturnCodeDetails());
```

Comment: I think you could just use that methods in your JSF managed bean.

Comment: Need more details what authentication information required ?!!